# Is it possible to convert a blob file into a base64Data in Javascript (Ionic,Angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, blob

[image: This is the error I am getting][[image: enter image description here][1]]

```js
async FileZip() {
    const code = await fetch("./assets/input.txt")
    var blob = await downloadZip([code]).blob()
     console.log(blob);

 
   function blobToBase64(blob: Blob): Observable<string> {
      return new Observable<string>(observer => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onerror = observer.error;
          reader.onabort = observer.error;
          reader.onload = () =>                     observer.next(reader.result as string);
          reader.onloadend = observer.complete;


    FileSharer.share({
      filename: "input.zip",
      base64Data: //base64datawillbehere ,
      contentType: 'application/zip'
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  })
```

I am pretty new to Ionic and App Development.
I have compressed a text file into a zip blob file using [client-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-zip) library. Using the downloadZip() I am getting a  [zip blob file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBGzE.png) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt3EP.png).
I want to share this file as a zip file using [Capacitor Filesharer](https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-filesharer) . But to use this Filesharer plugin , it seems I have to convert this blob zip file into base64 data.
Can anyone tell how to do it ?? Or is it even possible to do this ??

Please forgive me If you find my question too immature ,because as I said I am pretty new to javascript .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code -

```js
fileZip() {
constcode = awaitfetch("./assets/input.txt");
varblob = awaitdownloadZip([code]).blob()
console.log(blob);
varreader = newFileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
reader.onloadend = ()=> {
constresult = reader.resultasstring;
constbase64Data = result.split(',')[1];
console.log(base64Data)
FileSharer.share({
filename:"json.zip",
base64Data,
contentType:'application/zip'
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the following function:

```
function blobToBase64(blob: Blob): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable<string>(observer => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = observer.error;
        reader.onabort = observer.error;
        reader.onload = () => observer.next(reader.result as string);
        reader.onloadend = observer.complete;
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to implement it in the Fileshare plugin, but in the local host I am getting this error---   ""Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': the string to be decoded is not currently encoded.  """

Comment: Hi,I  have added the code, If possible please check

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your code as demonstrated below: (haven't changed the previous answer as it might be useful for others to implement such operations using **Observable** strategy unlike your case where I would recommend of using **Promise**)

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.fileZip();
}

private blobToBase64(blob: Blob): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.onabort = reject;
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  })
}

private async fileZip(): Promise<void> {
  const code = await fetch("./assets/input.txt")
  const blob = await downloadZip([code]).blob();
  const base64Data = await this.blobToBase64(blob);
  await FileSharer.share({
    filename: "input.zip",
    base64Data: base64Data,
    contentType: "application/zip",
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code which you provided, but I am getting the same error-""  core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.
Error: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded. ""

Comment: can you find out which line the error was thrown at? try using  breakpoints...

Comment: I have attached the screenshots here